# remove articles in front page joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla

I want to remove articles in front page, so I removed all featured articles but I have applied padding value for that articles. Thus this is showing the space in front page even there is no featured article. How could I use if function that if there is articles then only to show otherwise not.

Such as we could do

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('position-12')): ?>
<div id="top"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-12"   />
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How could I wrap with if function for this:

```
<jdoc:include type="message" />
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

Comment: Have you tried applying padding to the child element instead?

Comment: I need to give padding to #top or margin to #top.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (JRequest::getVar('view') != 'frontpage'): ?>
     <jdoc:include type="message" />
     <jdoc:include type="component" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But it's not working. I think 'frontpage' is removed in joomla2.5 this should be something like 'featured'.